# TypeScript and Angular return array of string

Tags: typescript, angular9

I'm creating a function who can filter data from array , filter provide from localstorage array :

I have created this function

```
 filtreData(): string {
if (this.filtres !== undefined) {
for (let i = 0; i < this.filtres.length ; i++) {
  let item = this.filtres[i].filtreValue; // this.filtres come from local storage
  return item;

}
}
```

The problem is that it's return me only one value . I want this return me all values tho show in this code :

```
<ng-template #noResultsSch>
      <li class="list-group-item example-box">
        <h3>No results for"{{filtreData()}}".</h3>
      </li>
</ng-template>
```

For the moment it return me only the last value.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
  filtreData(): string[] {
      let result=[];
      if (this.filtres !== undefined) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.filtres.length ; i++) {
          let item = this.filtres[i].filtreValue; // this.filtres come from local storage
          result.push(item);
        }
      }
    return result;
    }
```

Comment: Worked but if I got "aa,bb,cc" in my array , and I make a filter on "sfsdf,aa" it will not return me "aa" but "no results". I have to make a || operator , but where ?

Comment: did not understood, it works as ||, you have to put "return" before the last }, not before this point, have you done it correctly? Because the behaviour you described is obtained by putting it before 2 of } not one

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array without the whole for loop e.g.

```
return this.filtres.map(e -> e.filtreValue)
```